# Copy from unknown file to a text file in C

Tags: c, linux, file, fopen, fwrite

I have a question about copying from an unknown bin file to a text file in C. 
Example from a terminal input in linux(command to run a program): `./program -f file.txt <file.bin` in this case -f is a flag from a switch case, file.txt is a text file to which contents are copied and if the file does not exists it will be created and file.bin is a file from which you will copy content but you don't know the name of the file.

Edit:

```
if(o == 1){
    FILE *f;
    char ch;

    f = fopen(writeTarget, "wb+");

    while(fscanf(stdin, "%s", & ch)){
        printf("Read %s", ch);
        fputs(ch, f);
    }



    /*while(1) {
        ch = fgetc(stdin);
        if(ch == EOF) {
            break;
        } else {
            putc(ch, f);
        }
    }*/
    fclose(f);
}
```

this is the code I tried to use to print to the file from stdin using command `./main file.txt <file.bin` but it gets stuck in infinite loop or I get Segmentation fault (core dumped). What am I missing here? In the comment there is another example what I've tried. The code in comments doesn't get stuck in an infinite loop and it creates a file if it doesn't exist but it doesn't print anything to it.

Comment: i know how to copy if you know the name of the second file but in this case I have no idea how to begin

Comment: If it is redirected like this, it will be `stdin`.

Comment: And the `FILE *` is already open when your process starts, so you don't need to call `fopen()`.  Just use `fread()` (or another function) on `stdin`.

Comment: ok i got it now... another problem how to write from stdin to a file